# Problemas con sentencia SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy realizando consultas SQL y no me funciona, ¿Sabéis si así esta bien la sintaxis?

```
$consulta = "SELECT * 
        FROM TipoVehiculo
        INNER JOIN VehiculoFlota
        ON VehiculoFlota.idtipo=TipoVehiculo.idtipo
        INNER JOIN Empresa 
        ON Empresa.idnombreempresa=VehiculoFlota.idnombreempresa
        WHERE disponibilidad LIKE 'Si'";
```

**Tabla TipoVehiculo**

```
idtipo  marca   modelo

22      seat    ibiza
```

**Tabla VehiculoFlota**

```
idmatricula     idtipo  idnombreempresa     disponibilidad  
locamatricula   22      juguetos            Si
33333           22      yoqse               Si
matriculayob    22      filomena            Si
```

**Tabla Empresa**

```
idnombreempresa

juguetos

yoqse

filomena
```

Comment: **Que problema te da?** Lo unico que veo es que el WHERE no indica la tabla de la que escojes el campo **disponibilidad**. Creo que deberia ser algo como **WHERE VehiculoFlota.disponibilidad  LIKE 'Si'**

Comment: No tiene sentido usar Like 'Si'. Si usas like es para buscar con comodines, de otra forma usa '='.

Comment: WHERE  VehiculoFlota.disponibilidad = 'Si'

Answer (score 2):

**¿Cual es el problema que tienes?**

A mi me funciona correctamente: [Ejemplo Aqui](http://rextester.com/WPZSV50569)

- En tu **WHERE** no indicas a que tabla pertence la columna **disponibilidad**, pero por no estar presente en otra tabla de las que usas en tu `Query` no hay problema ahora, sin embargo deberias especificar a que tabla pertence para evitar problemas futuros.
- Al final usas el **LIKE** y como lo mencionan en los comnetarios si vas a comprar un valor usa **=**, si vas a buscar por comodines usas **LIKE**, por ejemplo `idmatricula LIKE 'matri%'`

Answer (score 0):

intenta esto.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Empresa INNER JOIN (TipoVehiculo INNER JOIN VehiculoFlota ON VehiculoFlota.idtipo = TipoVehiculo.idtipo) ON Empresa.idnombreempresa= VehiculoFlota.idnombreempresa
 where disponibilidad='si';
```